# Cocenter is a free module over the center in a semisimple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

Let $R$ be a semisimple (noncommutative) ring. Why is the cocenter $R/[R,R]$ of $R$ a free module over the center of $R$? (Here $[R,R]$ is the commutator of $R$.)